# What software was used to make these prototypes and diagrams?

Tags: prototyping

A book "ASP.NET MVC 1.0 Test Driven Development" contains pictures like

[image]

and

[image]

Unfortunately Emad Ibrahim (the book's author) doesn't know what software was used, he told the publisher did it for him.

Maybe you know what it is. I believe it isn't [Balsamiq Mockups](http://balsamiq.com/).

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know what program the author used to create these specific mock-ups, but I know of two programs you can use to create similar prototypes and diagrams.

For diagrams, I've found that [SimpleDiagrams](http://www.simplediagrams.com/) is an excellent "virtual pen and paper" program for creating freestyle diagrams without getting in your way. It's also very cheap as far as prototyping tools go: $19 for a personal use license.

For prototyping, there are plenty of tools to choose from. [Pencil](http://pencil.evolus.vn) (there is also a standalone version of the application) seems to be a fairly useful tool if you're only looking for a tool to do rough sketches of the UI when detailing the UI requirements. This tool and many others have been [discussed in detail elsewhere already](https://stackoverflow.com/q/112803/443986), and won't be re-hashed here.

Hope this helps!